# How is this question too broad?

Tags: discussion

[How to respond to a brother with the basic attitude: "You are right and I have my peace"?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/9178/how-to-respond-to-a-brother-with-the-basic-attitude-you-are-right-and-i-have-m)

I do not understand how this closed question is too broad. It is restricted to a specific interpersonal issue with one person and seems to provide adequate details about the problem.

I voted to reopen because it didn't look broad to me. Then I thought it would be useful to know why the Q got closed:

Can someone explain how it is too broad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) Who is *We*?**

Is it just the OP, i. e. the younger sibling, asking for a way to tell something to their brother, or does it include their parents also? If so, which one of the parents or both and do they want to tell them at the same time or one after another? Also, coming from their parents or their younger brother certainly makes a difference.

**2. What about the situation?**

> The biggest problem with that is the basic attitude towards every problem: You are right and I have my peace.

Perhaps, that's indeed his attitude to every problem, although offering a solution to that would be beyond the scope of IPS.SE. Apart from that, we don't know much about those problems. We can't judge what's wrong about the brother's response in the second paragraph. The OP only shares more details in the third paragraph, but there the situation involves their parents - see (1). It's also not clear, if that's exactly the situation the OP wants to see solved, or an example to make clear, that their brother replies like that to their parents, too. So, is it relevant that the OP and their parents have to clean up the table themselves, for example?

**3. What has been tried so far?**

Tinkeringbell asked in a comment

> Since you already seem to know what you want to say, have you actually tried saying exactly that? How did your brother react to that? Why not let your parents parent your brother?

yet didn't receive a reply. But it would be good to know, what approaches have been tried so far, for users to not repeat that in answers.

**4. What's the goal?**

> How can we tell him how annoying he is in a simple way

Does the OP merely want to tell their brother, that he is annoying? And they hopes for answers consisting of sample phrases that may or may not work? And then we're back at (3): Did they already tell him that it's annoying?

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed and convincing assessment @Anne Daunted. I am [linking](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/9178/how-to-respond-to-a-brother-with-the-basic-attitude-you-are-right-and-i-have-m#comment35568_9178) the original Q to this meta. OP can follow your valuable advice and edit their question adequately if they want to get it reopened.

Answer (score 3):

First, there's this sentence in the question:

> "Arguing that you don’t care about the right to privacy because you have nothing to hide is no different than saying you don’t care about free speech because you have nothing to say"

Then, immediately after OP posted their question, they also posted this comment:

> The phrase is very effective because you can't reply anything in order to invalide it. A phrase like that would be the best answer I can imagine! – [monamona](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/9178/how-to-respond-to-a-brother-with-the-basic-attitude-you-are-right-and-i-have-m#comment35402_9178)

So, I posted this comment:

> Since you already seem to know what you want to say, have you actually tried saying exactly that? How did your brother react to that? Why not let your parents parent your brother? – [Tinkeringbell](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/9178/how-to-respond-to-a-brother-with-the-basic-attitude-you-are-right-and-i-have-m#comment35408_9178)

I believe that comment perfectly sums up all the details that are missing in this question. Has the OP tried saying what they said in the question? How did the brother react to that? And why not let his parents parent his brother, why does OP need to do that?

**This question is too broad, it's lacking detais that need to be provided *by the OP* before we can reopen this question**

Comment: It's also missing culture and the gender of the sibling, FWIW.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed and convincing assessment @Tinkeringbell. I am [linking](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/9178/how-to-respond-to-a-brother-with-the-basic-attitude-you-are-right-and-i-have-m#comment35568_9178) the original Q to this meta. OP can follow your valuable advice and edit their question adequately if they want to get it reopened.

Comment: *"It's also missing culture and the gender of the sibling"* __ Thanks for noting that here, @Arwen Undómiel.

Comment: @EnglishStudent, please don't act like taking 10 minutes for reinstating what's already in there in the comments is equal to writing a book that can earn the Nobel prize for literature.... It's annoying.

Comment: It is something to do with the formal structure of Indian English. All that I write becomes extremely polite. Kindly excuse @Tinkeringbell.